# How can I use servicestack product so I can connect my Flutter or Dart to soap WSDL services?

Tags: soap, dart, servicestack

I am trying to get my Flutter app to connect securely to soap/wsdl web services.

My question is how can I use servicestack product so I can connect my Flutter Mobile App or Dart console App to consume soap WSDL services?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://nick.mobile.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://nick.mobile.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://nick.mobile.com/">
      <s:element name="C_getFilteredCustInfo_WithAssignNo">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AssignNo" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="clSecurityCheckBase" type="tns:cpSecurityCheckBase_WithAssignNo" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="language" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="cpSecurityCheckBase_WithAssignNo">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AssignNo" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OrgData" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HashData" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IP" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack's [Dart and Flutter support](https://docs.servicestack.net/dart-add-servicestack-reference) relies on [using the JsonWebClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/dart-add-servicestack-reference#flutter-and-dart-vm-usage) with generated Typed DTOs, e.g:

```
import 'package:servicestack/client.dart';

import 'techstacks.dtos.dart';

var client = new JsonServiceClient("https://www.techstacks.io");

main() async {
  var response = await client.get(new GetTechnology(slug: "flutter"));
  print("${response.technology.name}: ${response.technology.vendorUrl}");
}
```

Which only works with ServiceStack's JSON endpoints, so you wouldn't be able to use it to call SOAP Services directly.

Instead as [ServiceStack support SOAP Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support) as an additional endpoint for your ServiceStack Services you could have the same Service available from both JSON as well as SOAP 1.1/1.2 clients.

Comment: I need to use post to get some data back and I only use PUT once. so the soap services returns xml data as well as sending xml data. My problem is that there is no Dart or Flutter example out there. Before I buy the product I need to make some demo example. how can I do that?

Comment: @Nick ServiceStack doesn't provide support for sending SOAP requests with its [dart client libraries](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-dart). I'm suggesting for your Dart client to call the JSON endpoints whilst your other SOAP clients can call the SOAP endpoints. Also you can [evaluate within the free quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) without a license.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am still new so I am not sure how to achive this. My problem is that client only support soap wsdl web services. So my flutter or dart must connect to that soap wsdl services. ???

Comment: @Nick By client do you mean your Customer or HTTP Client? I don't expect anyone to have developed a SOAP client for Flutter (given how bad SOAP is), IMO the best/only way is to [construct the raw SOAP XML and send it with a HTTP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31713404/85785).

Comment: Sorry for my English. I am developing a mobile apo to client. He send me some  wsdl document that shows how to consume some data. But I dont know how to construct raw soap xml and send it with a http client. But I will check the link that you just provided. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick Basically you'd need to create the raw XML SOAP string and post it via HTTP Post, see these answers in [sending SOAP requests in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53505624/85785). You'd need to determine the exact XML yourself, if you have access to a working SOAP client I'd use a HTTP packet sniffer like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the XML they send so you can post it as a raw XML string in your client.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have a wsdl document, but I have no idea how to read it. Only once I created raw xml data and send it  using the http library for OTP msg. I never use wsdl before and I dont have any idea how to read it to know what can be needes to create a raw xml. Can I post here part of the wsdl tommorow so at least you can tell me how to read?

Comment: @Nick WSDL is just a schema/contract to define how to call the SOAP Service you'd need to create the XML that validates against it. As per my previous comment I'd recommend getting access to an existing App that's calling your SOAP Services and use a packet sniffer to capture the XML so you know what to send. Otherwise there are products like [XMLSpy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor) that could create sample XML from a WSDL, otherwise the alternative is to learn WSDL and manually create the XML yourself.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding I have a xml and I updating my question. Based on the update how to create a xml myself?

Comment: @Nick read my previous link for [sending SOAP requests in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53505624/85785).

Comment: I understand you perfectly now. I will try to use XMLSpy to create a xml from my wsdl. Thank you very much.